# Listen to object change in AWS S3 (AWS SDK)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In AWS S3, I have a bucket named `'my-bucket'`, under `my-bucket` I have the following structure:

```
my-bucket/
    customers/
         products/
              - data1.txt
              - data2.txt
```

with [AWS Ruby SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/), I can list all the items under `my-bucket` by ruby code:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-2')

bucket = s3.bucket('my-bucket')

# Show only the first 50 items
bucket.objects.limit(50).each do |item|
  puts "Name:  #{item.key}"
end
```

This is fine, I am wondering is it possible to have a **listener** listen to any new file object uploaded to `my-bucket/customers/products/` with AWS Ruby SDK? If possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be done directly with code.
What you can do, however, is have a listener on a `SQS` queue (that you can do with code) and create an event in `S3` for pushing a message to a queue on every change that is done in your bucket.

For `SQS` documentation please [follow here](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) (it is very straightforward).

For configuring an event you can follow this [detailed link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), and for a shorter version of this, do as follows (create a `SQS` queue first):

1. Go to your bucket (through the *AWS Console*).
2. Click the *Properties* tab (on the upper-left corner).
3. Expand *Events*.
4. Click *Add notification*.
5. Choose the type of events you'd like to listen to.
6. **Optional,** if you want the event to apply on objects with a specific prefix, specify the prefix.
7. **Optional,**, same for suffix.
8. Send it to *SQS Queue*.
9. Put the queue's `ARN`.

Now, all you need to do with `Ruby`, is listen (with a polling mechanism) to new message on the queue.
The messages will have some `JSON` format in some schema, play with it.

That should solve your problem.